# conditionalPanel and renderImage shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a input panel that takes the result of the first panel, and then changes the 'choices' vector in the other panel. The variable `allpath4` was loaded in the same way as `org`.

```
 selectInput("org", "Choose an organism:", 
              choices = org ),

  conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.org != 'NA'",
              selectInput("path", "Choose a pathway:", 
                   choices =allpath4[grep(strsplit("input.org", "-")[[1]][1], allpath4[,1]),2] )
           )
```

The error I receive is because I can't read the `input$org` inside function, how can I do that?

In a related topic I'm trying to use `renderImage` to allow me to load I image that I'm downloading each time the parameter from input panel change, for example

```
url <- paste("http://www.kegg.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?", input$org, "+default%3dred+", sep="")
download.file(url, paste('file', inorg, '.png', sep=''))
```

If I use

```
output$plot2 <- renderImage({
       # A temp file to save the output. It will be deleted after renderImage
       # sends it, because deleteFile=TRUE.
   inorg <- input$org 
   filename <- normalizePath(file.path('./',
                  paste('file', inorg, '.png', sep='')))


       # Return a list
       list(src = filename)
     })
```

I can load the correct image the first time that I load the app, but them if I change the inputs in `selectInput` the new figure is not loaded. Any guess?

Comment: `"input.org"` is not an R variable. `strsplit("input.org", "-")` is nonsensical. The use of `"input.org"` is in a JavaScript setting. Other then that you will need to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @jdharrison, thanks for your reply, I edited the question, with a link for the code, and a running example.

Comment: Is there a reason you're now downloading the file inside of the `renderImage` block? I'm working if it has something to do with the file not being downloaded yet when `renderImage` tries to update.

Comment: I would try to download in a observer : `observe({ download.file(url, paste('file', input$org, '.png', sep='')) })`.  I'm not sure but I think that the observer should be executed before the other dependencies to `input$org`, and if I'm right this should work.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick and @Stéphane, I've moved the `dowload.file`, to `renderImage` and it did the trick. What about `conditionalPanel` can I change my second panel as a function of a first one?